# Rails Engines: Accessing an images under an engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

We have a view under an engine that is supposed to show an image. this image (Button-Blank-Red-icon.png) is saved under the engine's path of "app/assets/images/engine_name/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png

I am getting the below error when trying to display this view.

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/images/<>engine_name>/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png"):

What's the right way to display an image stored under engine's app/assets/images/engine_name/?

Here is the view code:

```
<img src="<%= RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS[r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator] %>"  height="15" width="15" />
```

`r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator` returns one of 'green', 'red' and 'yellow'

The definition of constant RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS is in my_constant.rb under engine's config/initializers/:

```
RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS = {
                         'green'  => '/Button-Blank-Green-icon.png',
                         'red'    => '/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png',
                         'yellow' => '/Button-Blank-Yellow-icon.png'
                        }
```

One working solution with image tag (refers to episode#277 in railscasts.com):

```
<%=image_tag(RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS[r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator], size: '23x23') %>
```

There is no need of block .

The my_constant.rb is:

```
RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS = {
                         'green'  => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Green-icon.png',
                         'red'    => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png',
                         'yellow' => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Yellow-icon.png'
                        }
```

Comment: What's the call you're using for displaying the image? `image_path`?

Comment: Please post some code.  Did you compile your assets?

Comment: Just updated the post with a working solution with image_tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're displaying your image via an [AssetUrlHelpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html). Your view code needs to be changed to the following:

```
<img src="<%= image_path(RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS[r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator]) %>" 
  height="15" width="15" />
```

`image_path` is going to properly add the `assets` portion of the path, along with the hash generated by the asset pipeline, so that you get a correct url.

Comment: it shows nothing with image_path. There is no assets path added.

Comment: @user938363 I've hit a similar issue where `/asset` wasn't added. It was due to the asset code being executed only once prior to the assets being registered (kind of like your initializer code.) The solution ended up needing the path to be wrapped in a lambda so that it got executed each time, instead of just once. Hard to tell with the current code you've posted if you'd be running into this or not.

Answer (score 1):

The correct url should be "/assets/<>engine_name>/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png" because when rails compiles the assets it will just mix all the content of /images /stylesheets and /javascript for all the gems and your app/assets dir inside public/assets. It will just copy "<>engine_name>" folder and it's content there.

It's not clear where this: "/images/<>engine_name>/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png" comes from, I'm not sure how to get that from the code you show.

Try to change what you use to "/assets/<>engine_name>/..." and it should work.

You can try to compile your assets manually and look where the files go, just do "bundle exec rake assets:compile RAILS_ENV=production", you can safely delete /public/assets after that test to keep it clean.

Comment: After adding /images/engine_name", it causes an error "syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting ')'"

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `asset_path` helper?

```
<%= image_tag(asset_path("engine_name/#{RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS[r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator]}"), size: '23x23') %>
```

replace engine_name with the actual name of the engine app.

Comment: I wish your answer was marked as correct. I would not end up repeating it :)

Answer (score 1):

Images from engine are accessible via:

```
http://localhost:3000/assets/engine_name/image.png
```

So as you said

```
<img src="<%= asset_path(RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS[r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator]) %>"  height="15" width="15" />

RED_GREEN_YELLOW_CLS = {
                         'green'  => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Green-icon.png',
                         'red'    => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Red-icon.png',
                         'yellow' => 'engine_name/Button-Blank-Yellow-icon.png'
                        }
```

Will work.

p.s. I find r.step_qties.last.ontime_indicator personally insulting train wreck. :)